# PDF file size massive in MikTex

Tags: pdftex, miktex, latex3

I did my thesis in Latex/Linux using raw gs commands and managed to produce the whole 150page monster within a few megabytes. For brevity I've decided, some 10 years on, to use Miktex under windows and I'm finding the pdf sizes produced are prohibitively large. a 6 page document with 6 figures is creating a 20meg file size.

I would like some control of the image compression and I've searched for a reliable out of the box solution to this, given the vanilla Miktex/Texworks environment I am using and nothing has had an impact. I have thus tried:

```
\pdfminorversion=5 
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfobjcompresslevel=2
```

And , which seems preferable, I have also tried changing the the pdftex.cfg file using the following command line:

```
.\MiKTeX 2.9\pdftex\config>initexmf --edit-config-file .\pdftex.cfg
```

and entering the following options:

```
compress_level 9
image_resolution 120
pk_resolution 600
```

any suggestions?

Comment: If a six page document with 6 figures gets so large your images must be quite some monsters.

Comment: pdfTeX does not touch the image bitmap data and does not downscale them.

Comment: I'd be interested in the contents of the images as well. I've seen some monster images converted from PNG to EPS for "better quality", and then the whole thing converted to back to a PDF.

Comment: Can you make the images available for download and add a link here?

Comment: You may be better off to use an image editor (like GIMP) to reduce the resolution and/or use jpeg compression.